# TiddlyWiki on node-webkit not displaying content

Tags: node.js, wiki, node-webkit, tiddlywiki

I followed [the tutorial](http://tiddlywiki.com) (In the "Getting Started" section) on how to use TiddlyWiki with node-webkit. When I then run nw.exe it doesn't display anything.

Im on windows (64bit) and have installed the 32bit version for windows. Not sure what Im doing wrong or if its just a bug.

I have also tried adding index.html and package.json to an archive (called app.nw) and run it with nw.exe, but still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the instructions and couldn't get it to work either. I used TiddlyWiki 5.0.13-beta, Windows 64 bit, node-webkit 0.9.2. It throws an exception that it can't find sjcl.js. sjcl.js is packaged into TiddlyWiki.

I suggest to use TiddlyDesktop instead. It's node-webkit ready-made for TiddlyWiki. It works like a charm for me under Windows. You can get it here:
https://github.com/Jermolene/TiddlyDesktop/releases

I suspect the plain node-webkit solution has lost attention, now that there is TiddlyDesktop.

Comment: hmm.. ok. is there a solution where you can host it on a server an access is from multiple devices?

Comment: oh.. yes there is. http://tiddlywiki.com/static/TiddlyWiki%2520on%2520Node.js.html. This looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

The offending code is in bootprefix.js. When bootprefix runs it checks if it is using node and then assumes it is a Node JS file based system. One solution, on a per-TiddlyWiki basis is to modify the following code near the top of bootprefix.js, which is in a script tag in single file TiddlyWiki.

```
// Detect platforms
$tw.browser = typeof(window) !== "undefined" ? {} : null;
$tw.node = typeof(process) === "object" ? {} : null;
$tw.nodeWebKit = $tw.node && global.window && global.window.nwDispatcher ? {} : null;

if($tw.nodeWebKit) $tw.node = null; //this is the line to add.
```